# How to update betas each time step with optimizer adam?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, backpropagation

When implementing the adam optimizer algorithm each time step the betas must be updated.

A static decay schedule can be used, although the paper recommend the following:

```
beta1(t) = beta1^t
beta2(t) = beta2^t
```

I am not sure what t would represent. Is it a constant like 0.99?

Comment: It would make your question clearer to include the link to the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t$ is most possibly the time step, which would mean a decreasing $\beta_i$ as time goes.

Comment: ah t is an epoch literally. for each time step it's beta1^epoch. Each time I run back propagation I set epoch++;

Comment: Thanks for the vote and accepted answer @Nick. It'd be appreciated if you could share the paper (link) you mentioned in the original post, and make your question clearer.